# Serialized data in a MySql Database to use in a Business Intelligence tool

Tags: mysql, serialization, business-intelligence

I have a database (MySql) and need to store some results from a web service monthly. 
The data can have 10 results today but may have 200 next month.

I need to use a BI tool to create charts and what not.

Someone proposed to serialize the data and save the blobs in the database, while the solution seems to work, I have a gut feeling that when the time comes to hook it up with the BI tool, hell will break loose.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Thanks

Edit: adding extra info.

The problem is that we haven't chosen the BI tool yet. But what it needs to do is create charts for the results. Some of the results come from Google Analytics. So we will be charting number of visitors to a site for the last 6 months. Or Number of viewed pages.

Comment: This is very, very hazy and probably impossible to answer without knowing what the Business Intelligence tool needs to do, and using what data in what format. Why not do a test run?

Comment: Sorry, I know it is hazy. 
The problem is that we haven't chosen the BI tool yet. But what it needs to do is create charts for the results.

Some of the results come from Google Analytics. So we will be charting number of visitors to a site for the last 6 months. 
Or Number of viewed pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: **do not store Serialized data in a database**.
Do some research, atomize your data and create data structure.
Once you've done it, you will be able to use any BI tool in the world.
That's the purpose of a database and what distinguishes a database from a flat file.